# sed: can't find label for jump to `omcat-users>/d'

Tags: sed, tomcat7

remove everything in a file from  to  in /etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml

```
sudo sed '/<tomcat-users>/,/</tomcat-users>/d' /etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml
```

error:

sed: can't find label for jump to `omcat-users>/d`

What is wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
sed '/<tomcat-users>/,/<\/tomcat-users>/d' /etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml
                     ---^
```

The `/` needs to be escaped

To remove that section from the input use the `-i` flag

> -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>
> ```
>      edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
> ```

i.e.

```
sed -i '/<tomcat-users>/,/<\/tomcat-users>/d' /etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml
```

Comment: I would like to remove this text from the file /etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml but it only show displays the text of the full file?!

Answer (score 2):

Why not just change the separator in `sed`

```
sed ':<tomcat-users>:,:</tomcat-users>:d' /etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml
```

Then you do not need to escape the `/`